# Angular - Autofill nested form by given data

Tags: angular

This is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-eez7wi?file=app/app.component.ts

Basically when I load the resources, it fills all expect the skill if entered more than 1.

```
setResourceDTOS() {
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.resourceDTOS;
    this.data.resourceDTOS.forEach((x) => {
      control.push(
        this.fb.group({
          seniority: x.seniority,
          skillDTOS: this.setResourceSkills(x),
          resourceNotes: x.resourceNotes,
        })
      );
    });
  }

  setResourceSkills(x) {
    let arr = new FormArray([]);
    x.skillDTOS.forEach((y) => {
      arr.push(
        this.fb.group({
          skill: y.skill,
        })
      );
    });
    return arr;
  }
```

And the for cycle which sets data for resources:

```
for (
      let currentLength = 0;
      currentLength < newdata.resourceDTOS.length - 1;
      currentLength++
    ) {
      this.setResourceDTOS();
    }

    this.myForm.patchValue(newdata);
```

How can I make so it also sets all the skills as well?

Comment: You're using the blank data which has only one skill to determine the number of skills in the form array. You should use the actual data to determine the number of form groups you push to the form array.

Comment: I'm using costum data that I put inside of it. I don't think that's the issue

Comment: When you patch the newdata there's nowhere for the additional skills to patch to, because you only add one skill in the form array (created using data, not newData). Add console logs inside the foreach to see this.

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://prnt.sc/1xvpy62

Comment: précisément - you'll want to use the newdata directly to decide how many skill formgroups to push.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be solved by deleting the `data` and using `newdata` instead.
Also, the `for` cycle is not necessary, so it can be deleted.

> When you patch the `newdata` there's nowhere for the additional skills to patch to, because you only add one skill in the form array (created using `data`, not `newdata`). Add console logs inside the `foreach` to see this. - [@Andrew Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4711754/andrew-allen)